# What is minimal work needed to reconnect existing socket to new server?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

Given the following pseudocode...

```
int sock = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
sockaddr_in si;
si.sin_family = AF_INET;
si.sin_port = 0;
si.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( inet_network( "127.0.0.100" ) );
bind( sock, (sockaddr*)&si, sizeof si );
...
struct sockaddr_in peer_addr;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.200", &peer_addr.sin_addr);
peer_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
peer_addr.sin_port = htons( 9000 );
connect( sock, (sockaddr*)&peer_addr, sizeof peer_addr) );
```

...assuming the `connect()` is successful, and is followed by the peer closing its respective sockets used with `listen()` and returned by `accept()`, is it possible to reuse `sock` as the argument to a subsequenet `connect()` with a different peer address?

Experimentally, the answer seems to be "no": although the second `connect()` returns `0`, the second peer to which I try to connect never returns from `accept()`. Can a knowledgeable answerer explain the nature of what is going wrong here? The `0` return value supposedly indicates success, so why might the peer `accept()` never unblock?

Is there something I can do to reuse `sock` to connect to a second peer? Or must that second `connect()` be done with a socket freshly-created by `socket()`? (I have verified that doing so works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is minimal work needed to reconnect existing socket to new server?

Infinite. It is impossible.

> is it possible to reuse sock as the argument to a subsequenet connect() with a different peer address?

No. You cannot reconnect a TCP socket once you have called `connect()`, even if it failed. You have to close it and create a new socket. One reason is that if the socket wasn't bound, `connect()` binds it, and that binding is chosen based on the IP route to the destination, which may not be the same for the second destination.

> although the second connect() returns 0

Hard to believe. Are you sure?

> the second peer to which I try to connect never returns from `listen()`.

`listen()` doesn't block. Do you mean `accept()`?

> Can a knowledgeable answerer explain the nature of what is going wrong here?

Again you must mean `accept()`, and again it is hard to believe in the second `connect()` returning zero.  `connect()` should have returned -1 with `errno == EISCONN` (or `WSAGetLastError() == WSAEISCONN` on Windows).

**EDIT** However calling `connect()` for a second time on a non-blocking socket is used to detect whether the first `connect()` has completed. This technique is in all the old books, but now that we have `SO_ERROR` the correct technique is to check `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` if you got `EAGAIN`/`EWOULBLOCK` from the first `connect()`. You do these checks when you get a write notification from `select()`, or a write or error notification from `(e)poll()`. So all that happened in your case was that the second `connect()` confirmed the success of the first `connect()`, and ignored the different target address/port.

> The 0 return value supposedly indicates success, so why might the peer `listen()` never unblock?

Whatever the appearance, the second `connect()` failed, so there was no reason for the server to do anything, let alone return from `accept()`.

> Is there something I can do to reuse sock to connect to a second peer?

No.

> Or must that second connect() be done with a socket freshly-created by socket()?

Yes.

Comment: "listen() doesn't block. Do you mean accept()?" - Yes, I guess I do. I've corrected my post.

Comment: "although the second connect() returns 0...Hard to believe. Are you sure?" I am sure about this. though. The observation perplexed me, prompting me to post the question. Your answer was very on-point, though, and addressed my question/confusion with nice specificity.

Comment: Check your code. `connect()` should have returned -1 with `errno == EISCONN` or `WSAGetLastError() == WSAEISCONN`.

Comment: While porting my real code to pseudocode, I think I neglected a detail that I thought was irrelevant, but is not: I set my socket to nonblocking (`fcntl( sock, F_SETFL, fcntl( sock, F_GETFL, 0 ) | O_NONBLOCK )`). I think this may explain why the second `connect()` returns `0`; the actual result would be revealed later, asynchronously, when the socket becomes writable, by means of `getsockopt(..., SO_ERROR, ...)`. Is this a plausible explanation for the second `connect()` returning `0`?

Answer (score 2):

> is it possible to reuse `sock` as the argument to a subsequenet `connect()` with a different peer address?

For a TCP socket, no it is not possible (for a UDP socket, it is allowed).  Once a TCP socket has been closed, it cannot be reused.  You need a separate `socket()` call for each `connect()` call.

HOWEVER, on Windows only, a `SOCKET` (from `socket()` or `WSASocket()`) *can* be reused, but *only* if it is closed using [`DisconnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737757.aspx) with the `dwFlags` parameter set to `TF_REUSE_SOCKET`.  Then the `SOCKET` can be passed to [`ConnectEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606.aspx) (or [`AcceptEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737524.aspx)).